# How to close an opened InfoBubble within event listener?

Tags: here-api

In my page, I have some markers and I want to show a title on each marker on hover. This was simple in Google Maps as we were using `title` parameter for `google.maps.Marker()` object. I couldn't find anything like in Here Maps and I decided to make a simple, similar one.

Now I have a `nokia.maps.map.Container()` which has one infobuble, one marker and two events: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. I can open infobubble in `mouseenter` event, but I can't close it in `mouseleave` event. I'm trying to use `closeBubble()`, but I'm unsuccessful.

Here is the fiddle of my work so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ffAKX/

How can I close that opened infobubble when mouse leaves marker object? Or is there any simple way to do this like `title` parameter of `google.maps.Marker()` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on the `InfoBubbles` component can be found [here](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/#topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.html). If you look at the `closeBubble()` method, you can see that it takes a bubble handle as a parameter. This needs to be remembered from the previous `openBubble()`

```
var infoBubbles = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles(),
    bubble;

map.components.add(infoBubbles);
container = new nokia.maps.map.Container();

container.addListener("mouseenter" ,  function(evt) {
    bubble =infoBubbles.openBubble(evt.target.html, evt.target.coordinate);   
}, false);

container.addListener("mouseleave" ,  function(evt) {
    infoBubbles.closeBubble(bubble); // I need to close infoBubble here
});
```

The result is very much like a tooltip, an actual [tooltip component](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#tooltip-component__index) can be found on the HERE Maps community pages

Comment: This works great, thank you. Looks like the tooltip component is the better idea.

Comment: I guess this depends on the version being used. This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731921/how-to-remove-previous-infobubble-if-i-click-different-marker-in-here-map

Comment: @Jason Fox, Hi, Is there any effect on app performance if we use MapOverlay class instead InfoBubble? Because I want to show multiple info bubbles at a time on each `MapMarker`, but it is not possible at this moment as per [doc](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapmarker.html#topic-apiref__showinfobubble-void). So I'm planning to use `MapOverlay`.

Comment: @roy-milller - The [HERE Android SDK](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/overview.html) and the [HERE JavaScript API](https://developer.here.com/develop/javascript-api) are two separate products. The `InfoBubble` discussion above relates to the JavaScript API.