# How to remove previous infobubble, if I click different marker in HERE Map?

Tags: javascript, here-api

Here below is my code to add an infobubble. I want to remove the current infobubble previously after click(tap) on a different marker.

```
function addInfoBubble(map) 
    {
    var group = new H.map.Group();
    map.addObject(group);
    // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
    group.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
    // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
    // for all objects that it contains
    var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
    // read custom data
    content: evt.target.getData()
    });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
    }, false);
    }
```

Where should I place the code line `ui.removeBubble(bubble)` if I click on a different marker?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could remove all infobubbles from ui just before adding a new one. If you don't mind removing all current bubbles being displayed, something like this should work:

```
ui.getBubbles().forEach(bub => ui.removeBubble(bub));
```

Incorporating it to your code:

```
function addInfoBubble(map) {
   var group = new H.map.Group();
   map.addObject(group);
   // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
   group.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
      // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
      // for all objects that it contains
      var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
        // read custom data
        content: evt.target.getData()
      });
      //remove infobubbles
      ui.getBubbles().forEach(bub => ui.removeBubble(bub));

      // show info bubble
      ui.addBubble(bubble);
   }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more in-depth summary of things you can do:

Remove the last infobubble that was created:

```
ui.removeBubble(bubbles[bubbles.length - 1])
```

Close the first infobubble that was created:

```
bubbles[bubbles.length - 1].close()
```

Remove the first infobubble that was created:

```
ui.removeBubble(bubbles[0])
```

Close all the bubbles:

```
bubbles.forEach((bubble) => {
    bubble.close()
});
```

Remove all the bubbles

```
while(bubbles.length > 0) {
   this.ui.removeBubble(bubbles[0])
}
```

Click on the infobubbles [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sainap/n9jk8e5u/) so you can try these out.