# How to close an info bubble when there is a click outside the info bubble and marker - HERE maps API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, here-api

I have been trying to close an info bubble when the map only is clicked, but I can't achieve it.

I have tried the following

```js
this.map.addEventListener("tap", this.handleMapClick);

    private handleMapClick(evt: Event) {
      this.clearOpenInformationBubble();
    }
```

However, the tap event is triggered even when maps objects are clicked meaning that the info bubble remains closed when I click a marker.

I have also tried to add a 'blur' event listener to the bubble element, but that doesn't seem to work

```js
const bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
      content: ...
    });

    this.ui.addBubble(bubble);

    bubble.getElement().focus()

    bubble.getElement().addEventListener('blur', evt => {
      this.clearOpenInformationBubble();
    })
```

I was wondering if there is a way to listen for an event triggered by a map ONLY tap.

Here's a similar implementation in Google maps.

```js
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, "click", function() {
      alert('Map clicked')
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731921/how-to-remove-previous-infobubble-if-i-click-different-marker-in-here-map). In this answer, they wanted to close any other open `infobubbles` first. I believe if you remove the event listener on your group, keep the one on your map, and always remove open `infobubbles` you would be good. *Then* add logic to see if the event target value has data and show an `infobubble`.

This assumes your doing `infobubbles` based on markers having a data object associated with them.

Edit:
I was able to get this to work - again assuming your use case is markers to `infobubbles`.

```js
map.addEventListener('tap', evt => {
    ui.getBubbles().forEach(bub => ui.removeBubble(bub));

    if(!evt.target.getData) return;
    // for all objects that it contains
    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
        // read custom data
        content: evt.target.getData()
    });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);

});
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. It's not an ideal solution as you rightly pointed out, because it falls apart if a marker isn't used to open the info-bubble. However, it works, and it's the best I have got now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the event target in the callback function.

If it is the map, then only you close the InfoBubble:

````js
this.map.addEventListener("tap", this.handleMapClick);

private handleMapClick(evt: Event) {
  if (evt.target === this.map) {
    this.clearOpenInformationBubble();
  }
}
    ```
````